# Java Spring Boot WAR works on Amazon EC2 java8/tomcat8 1.3.1, but not on 1.4.5 or 2.1.3

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot WAR with tomcat-embedded in the lib-provided folder (build using Gradle). When I deploy it on Amazon EC2 with their Linux Java8/Tomcat8 image version 1.3.1 it works perfectly, when I try to upgrade to their Liunx/Java8/Tomcat8 image version 1.4.5 or 2.1.3 the webapp doesn't work. No errors appear in the logs on the instance. Deploying the webapp on the latest Java8/Tomcat 8 release on my laptop works without problems.